# Convert Data to UInt32 using extension

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm trying to have a helper method for `Data` class to convert bytes to `UInt32`. So far this worked:

```
extension Data {    
    var uint32:UInt32 {
        return UInt32(littleEndian: self.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt32>) in ptr.pointee })
    }
}
```

Since swift 5 the compiler gives the following warning:

```
'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead`
```

After some research I tried to use `withUnsafeMutableBytes` along with `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>`

but this gives an error: `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`. (This would work if it wasn't a part of an inmutable getter function)

How can I fix my read only helper variable so the compiler doesn't give warnings?

(Of course the same applies to `UInt8` or `UInt16`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let data = Data([0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04])
extension Data {
    var uint32:UInt32 {
        return UInt32(littleEndian: self.withUnsafeBytes { bytes in
            bytes.load(as: UInt32.self)
        })
    }
}
print(String(format: "%08X", data.uint32)) //->04030201
```

The new `withUnsafeBytes` passes an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`, which has a useful method `load(as:)`.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR. I should have noted it. Frankly, I did not know I can make such a misaligned `Data` so easily.

Comment: (Previous comment deleted inadvertently.) This requires that the memory is properly aligned, it crashes e.g. for `let data = Data([0x00, 0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04]).dropFirst()`. – `Data` is its own slice type, and there is no guarantee that a given (or created) `Data` is aligned at all. Also discussed here: https://forums.swift.org/t/about-data-alignment/17447

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `self` to a `variable`

```
extension Data {
    var uint32:UInt32 {
        var data = self
        return UInt32(littleEndian: data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>) in ptr.pointee })
    }
}
```

Comment: It solves the error related to immutability but the result still has warnings. Seems `withUnsafeMutableBytes` is just as bad.